# Jquery Form Validation NOT USING model Annotations

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, jquery-validate

I have tried asking this question in a number of ways, and I still can't get an answer.  In Asp.net MVC4, is there a way I can just add jquery code to my views and not have to add any kind of annotation to a model to validate my form input?  I just realized that I am using Ajax.BeginForm...  I am betting that I cannot using regular Jquery Ajax calls with that on my form.  I bet if I use HTML.beginForm, regular jquery will work.  But now that will break my ajax calls... Which were failing for some reason.  Well, I am about to find out why.  Hopefully I can figure out how to just avoid using all Asp.net Ajax crap.  It has given me nothing but a massive headache.  Oh wait, you know what, I just looked at another view, and there I am using Html.BeginForm and I still can't use plain jquery code in my views to validate my form.  Is this even possible in MVC4?

Answer (score 0):

of course this is possible - ASP.NET MVC just emits HTML yes?  so just add some jquery validate code to the document ready.

```
$(function(){
 $('#myform').validate(/* options here */);
});
```